# How to get the sum of time from database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to get the sum of this column in my database and display it in home page. Here is the screen shot

http://bit.ly/1fJ7Cey

I use this code to save data on my Database

```
$timeanddate=$_POST['timeanddate'];
$time=$_POST['tst'];
$name=$_POST['name'];   
$number=$_POST['number'];
$disposition=$_POST['disposition'];
$remarks=$_POST['remarks'];
$times=$_POST['timetoday'];
$dates=$_POST['datetoday'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hsncs_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO hsncs_tbl (id, name, number, call_disposition, remarks, time, date, time_duration, hsncs_user)
VALUES
('', '$_POST[name]', '$_POST[number]', '$_POST[disposition]', '$_POST[remarks]', '$_POST[timetoday]', '$_POST[datetoday]', '$_POST[tst]', '$_SESSION[fname]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: one suggestion paste the whole link NO **short links**

Comment: The query you have to do is `SELECT SUM(time_duration) FROM yourtable;`

Comment: have you tried `select sum(time_duration) as sum from hsncs_tbl`?

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't work :(

Comment: I'm not convinced. Echo $sql

Comment: I tried this "$test = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(time_duration) FROM hsncs_tbl');" it displays Resource id #10

Comment: Take a look at a basic PHP Mysql tutorial for heavens sake! There are hundered out there, and some of them are good!

Comment: Your link appears to be broken; please upload the image using Stack Overflow’s image uploader.

Answer (score 1):

If this column time is of data type "**time**" in mysql then your query would be

```
SELECT  SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `time_duration` ) ) ) AS timeSum FROM hsncs_tbl;
```

Comment: i try this too, still now working... " $testr = mysql_query('SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time_duration)))) AS timeSum FROM hsncs_tbl'); " and echo it as " <?php echo $testr; ?> ".

Comment: Actually I used that just yesterday and it worked fine with my time field.